# Django multiple ModelForms from one Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need to implement a transaction with a step by step process wherein the user can input the details in step 1 and then process the inputted data which will do some calculations. The user can then proceed to step 2 which displays the initial result and he/she can input additional parameters to manipulate the results. I need to store all user inputs in one model so that if the user cancels the process, all data that was initially stored will be deleted.

I am a newbie in django and python so if anyone know how to solve this problem I would really appreciate it.

This is what I've tried so far:

In my **models.py** I have:

```
class Calculate(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    csv = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')

    CHOICES = (
       ('none', '(none)'),
       ('c1', 'C-1'),
       ('c2', 'C-2'),
       ('c3', 'C-3'),
    )

    param1 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, default='c1')
    param2 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, default='c2')
    param3 = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES, blank=False, default='none')
```

In my **forms.py** I have:

```
class DetailsInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Analysis
        fields = ('date_created', 'csv',)

class ParamInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Analysis
        fields = ('param1', 'param2', 'param3',)
```

In my **views.py** I have:

```
 class DetailsInputView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     model = Calculate
     form_class = DetailsInputForm
     template_name = 'step1.html'
     login_url = 'login'
     success_url = reverse_lazy('step2')

 class ParamInputView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
     model = Calculate
     form_class = ParamsInputForm
     template_name = 'step2.html'
     login_url = 'login'
```

In my html template I have:

```
 <div class="tab-pane">
      {% block step1 %}
      # block in step1.html
      {% endblock %}
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane">
      {% block step2 %}
      # block in step2.html
      {% endblock %}
 </div>
```

When I run my code, I got a programming error saying that db column param1, param2, and param3 does not exist. I suspect this is because the row in my database is incomplete because of the different ModelForms I used.

I don't even know if I'm still in the right track. I've done some researching for a while now and still haven't got any answer. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are forgetting a [required argument for your CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#charfield), `max_length`. This is the maximum number of characters that can be saved into that CharField.

Change you fields to something like this:

```
param1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Or whatever length you want to assign.

If you want to store large amounts of text, use `TextField` instead.

Secondly, most of the times when you get an error saying "Column *x* does not exist", it means you forgot to apply your migrations.

Running `python manage.py makemigrations`, followed by `python manage.py migrate` will generate migrations files, and then apply them to the database, in that order.

Do this everytime you make any changes to any Model in your Django applications.

Comment: Hi Sir @NicoGriffioen! I'm sorry about that I forgot to include the Model field references in the post but I have done it in my project. I did include max_length and made my migrations all the time. However, the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you should not be using `CreateView` for your second view (`ParamInputView`) because you want to update the object (database row) created by the first view. You probably want `UpdateView`, and to pass the id of the object created in the first through to the URL of the second.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now I'm trying to use django-formtools.